# Funciones para identificar una clave en diccionarios; Python

Tags: python, funciones, diccionarios

Estoy aprendiendo programación y en tengo un ejercicio en el que debo codificar y decodificar un mensaje. Para decodificarlo, use la función .get(), de manera que me mostrara la letra decodificada. Quiero hacer algo similar para codificarlo, usando el mismo diccionario. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Probé usando la función .keys(), pero evidentente no funcionó como quería. Salven mi temprana vida universitaria, por favor. Si me contestan les irá bien en el amor :)

Comment: Jajajajaja hola, Alejandro. Para que te ayudemos (y ergo, nos vaya bien en el amor), comparte tu código, lo que has intentado. Pero te adelanto que, si puedes, no trabajes con diccionarios. Para este tipo de tareas caen a la perfección dos métodos de la clase `str`: `maketrans()` y `translate()`.

Comment: El diccionario sólo funciona en una dirección. Conocida la clave, obtienes el valor. Si lo que necesitas es el inverso (dado el valor obtener la clave) necesitas crear otro diccionario que esté "a la inversa", en el que los valores sean las claves. Puedes crear un diccionario inverso como este así: `inverso = { valor: clave for clave, valor in diccionario.items() }`. Naturalmente no puede haber valores duplicados en el diccionario original.

Comment: Muchas gracias!